# Google script importing .csv to Google Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, csv, url, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have this Google script that imports .csv tables from URL to Google Spreadsheet (=importfeed, =importdata would not work as the separator in those files is semicolon), but I'm not sure how to edit it so that I could upload from URL that has a few pages of content. I'd like it to import content into sheets one after another.

Here's how URL looks like: https://example.com/feed?page=1&format=csv ; https://example.com/feed?page=2&format=csv ... https://example.com/feed?page=10&format=csv

Here's the script that I use:

```
    function importData() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var url = 'https://example.com/feed?page=1&format=csv';
    var file = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url); // get feed 

    var csv = file.getBlob().getDataAsString();
    var csvData = CSVToArray(csv); // see below for CSVToArray function
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    for (var i = 0, lenCsv = csvData.length; i < lenCsv; i++) {
        sheet.getRange(i + 1, 1, 1, csvData[i].length).setValues(new Array(csvData[i]));
    } 
};


// http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1504-Ask-Ben-Parsing-CSV-Strings-With-Javascript-Exec-Regular-Expression-Command.htm
// This will parse a delimited string into an array of
// arrays. The default delimiter is the comma, but this
// can be overriden in the second argument.

function CSVToArray(strData, strDelimiter) {
    // Check to see if the delimiter is defined. If not,
    // then default to COMMA.
    strDelimiter = (strDelimiter || ";");

    // Create a regular expression to parse the CSV values.
    var objPattern = new RegExp(
        (
            // Delimiters.
            "(\\" + strDelimiter + "|\\r?\\n|\\r|^)" +

            // Quoted fields.
            "(?:\"([^\"]*(?:\"\"[^\"]*)*)\"|" +

            // Standard fields.
            "([^\"\\" + strDelimiter + "\\r\\n]*))"
        ),
        "gi"
    );

    // Create an array to hold our data. Give the array
    // a default empty first row.
    var arrData = [
        []
    ];

    // Create an array to hold our individual pattern
    // matching groups.
    var arrMatches = null;

    // Keep looping over the regular expression matches
    // until we can no longer find a match.
    while (arrMatches = objPattern.exec(strData)) {

        // Get the delimiter that was found.
        var strMatchedDelimiter = arrMatches[1];

        // Check to see if the given delimiter has a length
        // (is not the start of string) and if it matches
        // field delimiter. If id does not, then we know
        // that this delimiter is a row delimiter.
        if (
            strMatchedDelimiter.length &&
            (strMatchedDelimiter != strDelimiter)
        ) {

            // Since we have reached a new row of data,
            // add an empty row to our data array.
            arrData.push([]);

        }

        // Now that we have our delimiter out of the way,
        // let's check to see which kind of value we
        // captured (quoted or unquoted).
        if (arrMatches[2]) {

            // We found a quoted value. When we capture
            // this value, unescape any double quotes.
            var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[2].replace(
                new RegExp("\"\"", "g"),
                "\""
            );

        } else {

            // We found a non-quoted value.
            var strMatchedValue = arrMatches[3];

        }

        // Now that we have our value string, let's add
        // it to the data array.
        arrData[arrData.length - 1].push(strMatchedValue);
    }

    // Return the parsed data.
    return (arrData);
};
```

Thanks a lot in advance. :)

Comment: What have you tried? If you know how the url changes, then use a loop to construct the respective urls and then call the importer with the relevant arguments (e.g. which sheet it should write to).

Comment: I'm not very good at javascript, so I was thinking maybe someone has any advice on how to do that. :)